# how to connect two table that has no relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, relational-database

I have a table called foods and categories, but this table has no relation, I want to connect them through another table called  food_category. And I want to make one-to-one relation between food and category maybe the diagram looks like this

[image]

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :food
end

class FoodCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :food
end
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason you want a join table for a 1-to-1 relationship? Why not directly relate foods and category by adding category_id to foods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to do

```
has_one :category, through: :food_categories
```

as discussed in the [Rails docs here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

However, this is a long-winded way to go about this kind of association. If it's going to be one-to-one, why not just add a foreign key to Category from Food? And presumably, you would actually want Category to contain *many* Food records? Seems like the below would make more sense:

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :food
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :food_category
  has_one :category, through: :food_categories
end
```

In rails console, you can access like this

```
Food.find(:id).categories
```